# Why can't I add a technical role?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to beta test my app, but for some reason I can't seem to find the technical role. I am logged in and am the admin and Legal role.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Maybe he is working at Apple and can't get the code to work? In that case we would want a lot more information about the bug that he is trying to fix :-)

Answer (score 2):

Technical has been replaced with App Manager.

If you look at user in iTunes Connect who has the Technical role it says:
Note: the Technical role will become App Manager. Please remove users from the Technical Role

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might not be strictly about code, but you can't release your app via TestFlight until you get past this mystifying problem.

The problem is caused because Apple will not allow an Apple ID that is associated with a developer account to be used for TestFlight (except for the account owner themselves).  In other words, because my Apple ID is associated with my developer account, none of my developer friends can invite that Apple ID to be a TestFlight user.  I must instead create a new Apple ID and ask them to invite that one.

The worst part of this particular bit of nonsense is that you use the same mechanism to invite developers and other team mates to work in iTunesConnect with you, and for those roles a developer account is irrelevant.  Only being a TestFlight user seems to be affected by whether or not you are using an Apple ID associated with a developer account.